# Left outer join between two datatable on linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, left-join

I have a two tables:

```
id | code      code | name
----------    -------------
1  | 001       001  | first
2  | 002       002  | second
3  | 001
```

Result must be

```
id | name
----------
1  | fisrt
2  | second
3  | first
```

My linq query:

```
var query = from content in result.Tables["Special_Contents_Tree"].AsEnumerable()
            join iNames in result.Tables["Special_Contents_ItemNames"].AsEnumerable()
            on content.Field<Nullable<Int16>>("Code") equals iNames.Field<Nullable<Int16>>("Code") into outer
            from gr in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
              ID = (Int16)content["ID"],
              Name = gr["Name"]
            };

DataTable SpecialContent = new DataTable();
SpecialContent.Columns.Add("ID");
SpecialContent.Columns.Add("Name");
foreach (var q in query)
{
   SpecialContent.Rows.Add(q.ID, q.Name);
}
```

But result is wrong - `result.Tables["Special_Contents_Tree"].Rows.Count = 323` then `SpecialContent.Rows.Count` should be too 323, but `SpecialContent.Rows.Count = 484`.

Comment: Did you take a look on your result? Why are there more rows? Duplicate values? are id in `Special_Contents_Tree` and code in `Special_Contents_ItemNames` unique?

Comment: @Uriel_SVK I find a mistake. You right. My second table contain a duplicate values in Code column.